# Different ErrorDocument based on current URL

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to rollout different error pages once their occures an internal server error.

I know you can define your own error pages using apache using that directive

```
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html
```

But, I want to show a human readale version on my frontpage, but ship an xml file once my api runs into an internal server error. I tried using RewriteCond, but even though there was no configuration issue I could not get the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your error document be a script in your preferred script language, and have the logic deciding what to show in the script rather than in Apache. If you don't want to do that, you will have to have separate directories where you have different error pages - the ErrorDocument directive can be put inside a <Directory> context.

Comment: mh but what if the server has actually a global problem and not one related to just one request. in that case I should expect my script not work as well so the regular error document gets shiped. I would prefer configuring that directly inside the webserver

Comment: If the server is having problems running any kind of script whatsoever, then obviously having a script as an error page won't work. But if the problem is that your application doesn't work, that doesn't necessarily mean that the error page would also be affected. To make an example - if your database is down, your application won't work, but a script that doesn't require the database still will. Or you can have your app in a subdir, and have a different error page just for the subdir

Comment: I undestand your point. Still I do not think that it is an satisfying solution, I will try it this way